# Secondary note being added Android studio

Tags: java, android

I am having a problem when creating a new note that it creates a secondary note. Every time that says welcome to notes, it's only supposed to create that note only once wants the app is installed. Can anyone help me out?

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
                // Going from MainActivity to NotesEditorActivity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NoteEditorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.echodev.Notes", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        if (set == null) {

            notes.add("Welcome To Notes!!!!!");
        } else {
            notes = new ArrayList(set);
        }
```

Comment: So "welcome to notes" created twice?

Comment: Where do you actually save the shared preferences when you add the "Welcome" note?

Comment: @Mahi It is actually making it after every time I create a new note

Comment: @Gardener full code https://pastebin.com/MiTGLu7j

Comment: Can you post the relevant code where you insert the newly created note to the sharedpreferences?